# button in dataview not firing after callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, callback, devexpress, dataview

I have an aspxdataview with images and buttons on it:

```
         <dx:ASPxDataView  ID="ASPxDataView1" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="dataview" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" SettingsTableLayout-RowsPerPage="2" Width="850px" PagerAlign="Justify" ItemSpacing="25px" OnCustomCallback="ASPxDataView1_CustomCallback" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <dx:ASPxImage ID="imgCover" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PhotoUrl") %>' Width="200px" Height="200px" ShowLoadingImage="true" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="X" runat="server" BackColor="Red" OnClientClick="return confirmPost()" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' Width="125px" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnRename" runat="server" Text="átnevez" OnClick="btnRename_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

When I upload an image the uploadcontrol calls a callback..

```
       <dx:ASPxUploadControl ID="ASPxUploadControl1" runat="server" UploadMode="Standard" Width="280px"
     (...)
        <ClientSideEvents FileUploadComplete="function(s, e) { dataview.PerformCallback('added'); }" />
```

..the handler then invokes databind on the dataview:

```
        protected void ASPxDataView1_CustomCallback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
    {ASPxDataView1.DataBind();}
```

The problem is that although the new item with the image appears, the delete button **in it** doesn't fire the click event (but some of the data items still disappear from the page when i click it), only after reloading the page.
I'm getting very frustrated so I set a bounty on the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment..but I don't have reputation.. sorry

Did you get any Javascript errors? (In developer tools)

----------------------------------------------------------

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="X" runat="server" BackColor="Red" OnClientClick="return confirmPost()" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
```

Try change to this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="X" runat="server" BackColor="Red" OnClientClick="return confirm("Are you sure?");" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
```

Comment: I saw that there's a confirmPost javascript method

Comment: I think that did you made a method called "confirmPost" in code behind? or can you post the confirmPost method?

Comment: function confirmPost(){
        var agree = confirm("Are you sure?");
        if (agree) return true;
        else return false;

Comment: still no success; but it has nothing to do with my confirmPost function. It is all very unpredictable

Comment: is it because of the double quotation in OnClientClick function? try change to single quotation

Comment: it has nothing to do with this js function, I'm absolutely sure